How to use wallet.dat file on Android?
Simple question. How to import non segwit addresses from a wallet.dat file ?
The problem is I can no longer afford a computer and Bitcoin core doesn’t really run on android.

Bitcoin core is available for Windows, MacOS and Linux but not Android or iPhone. Consequently, the authors of wallet sofware for phones might not expect people to have a wallet.dat file from Bitcoin core on their phone. Similarly, authors of tools for extracting wallet.dat contents might assume people needing to do this have a desktop computer or laptop. You may be seeking a Unicorn.

@RedGrittyBrick correct. I need something for importing wallet.dat
